# Calculus terminology : derivative/integral/limit

Tags: calculus, terminology

I'd like to make a classification while coding a simple CAS system. I don't know how to classify the derivative, the integral and the limit.

Can they be considered as function ? as operators ? as applications ? other ?

I can't find precise informations on the web. If anybody has a good classification of calculus I take it !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say "operators"

Comment: I'd say they're functions and operators. "Applications" as far as I know is not used in English and is usually a mistranslation of French.

Comment: Sorry Matt I'm french, that's why I use this term ;-) . You say function and operator, for derivative, the integral AND the limit or you make a distinction between the three ones ?

Comment: @rperrot The limit is similarly a linear function/operator except for the caveat that it can fail to be linear with infinities.

Comment: @reporrot The limit usually isn't treated that way because it's less useful to do so (as far as I've seen), but the derivative and integral are definitely treated like functions/operators.